# How to ensure that a pin never floats

Tags: dac

I am making a DAC circuit with uses an [AD7541A](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7541A.pdf) chip which is going to be connected to another board with a microcontroller on it. Now the AD7541A gets fried if someone turns it on while all the pins are floating. So I want to ensure that even if someone accidentally turns on the circuit with pins floating, the chip does not fry. So what can I do to ensure that?

Comment: Use pull-down resistors on every input pin

Comment: What makes you think your DAC will fry if it's turned on with all the pins floating? If a device is going to eat itself if it's pins are floating, I would think they would make some mention of that in the datasheet. And if pullup or pulldown resistors are required, that too is usually mentioned. None of the example circuits have these. It sounds like there is something else going on here. Can you post a schematic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Assumption**: Based on the wording of the question, presumably certain input pins must not be floating to a "high" condition when the AD7541A is powered on.

The conventional method of preventing a pin from floating, i.e. ensuring that it is held low until some logic state is imposed upon it by an external device, is to use a pull-down resistor on the pin in question.

A pull-down resistor is simply a resistor of high value, connected between the pin in question, and the circuit ground. The value of the resistor should be high enough than the external device that needs to assert a value upon the pin at some time, is not unduly loaded, or in the case of analog input pins, unduly distorted in overcoming the resistor's effect.

Common pull-down values are 10 kOhms or 100 kOhms. For analog inputs that must be held low until externally asserted, sometimes 1 MegaOhm resistors are used. The selection of resistor value must be such that it is significantly higher than the output impedance of the pin or device that will be asserting a value on the pulled-down pin during normal operation. At the same time, too high a resistance value will leave the pin susceptible to stray noise pulling the pin high on occasion.

The reason for using very high values for analog inputs, when a pull-down is used at all, is that if the source impedance the analog input is to read is of comparable magnitude to the pull-down resistance, the combination will act as a voltage divider, lowering the voltage seen by the analog input during operation.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't looked at that datasheet, but what's wrong with the usual method of putting weak pulldown resistors on every pin that you don't want to float?  If these are CMOS inputs, then 100 kΩ should do it.  If you think there might be a lot of noise, you can use lower values.  Assuming these pins are driven by normal digital outputs once everything is powered up, you have a wide latitude.  There is plenty of room between low enough to keep the pin low during power on, and high enough to not significantly load the digital outputs when they are trying to drive high.

Depending on your application, the current draw of all those pulldown resistors when the digital signals are high may also matter.  For example, the digital outputs may be able to overcome 1 kΩ pulldowns, but that would be 3.3 mA each with 3.3 V logic.  That can add up.  Fortunately, you shouldn't need pulldowns anywhere near as strong as 1 kΩ.